# Do rocket labs store propellants at higher pressure than the other rockets?

Tags: rockets, liquid-fuel, spacecraft-development, electron, tanks

It is known that the Rutherford engines run on an electric pump-fed cycle. There must be a trade-off between the tank pressure of the electron rocket and battery capacity, for batteries are dead weight on board. To reduce the amount of battery dead-weight the tank can be at a slightly higher pressure. Too much tank pressure, and the structural weight increases.

So an optimal pressure for the propellant tank can help a lot and this might be higher than the usual pressure at which the propellants are stored in conventional rockets.

What is the tank pressure of Electron rocket?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric-pump-fed_engine): "An electric cycle engine uses electric pumps to pressurize the propellants from a low-pressure fuel tank to high-pressure combustion chamber levels, generally from 0.2 to 0.3 MPa (29 to 44 psi) to 10 to 20 MPa (1,500 to 2,900 psi). The pumps are powered by an electric motor, with electricity from a battery bank." Tank pressure is 2 to 3 bar, pump output pressure is 100 to 200 bar.